# overflow menu shown as a contextual menu in android appcompat

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar-compat

I am using android-support-v7-appcompat for backward compatibility as i want to use ActionBar in my app.I have added the menu in my .

Here is my `menu.xml`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:DetailsPage="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

   <!--  <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/> -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
        DetailsPage:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        DetailsPage:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        android:title="Search Products">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/root_menu"
        DetailsPage:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"
        android:title="More">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_Home"
                DetailsPage:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="Home"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_favourite"
                DetailsPage:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="favourite"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_Balance"
                DetailsPage:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="Balance"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
                DetailsPage:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
                android:title="Logout"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

In My Activity, i have extends my activity with ActionBarActivity and

Here is my `onCreateOptionsMenu` ::

```
public boolean  onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
}
```

Currently on click of the menu item it is shown like this ::

[image]

Here the menu is displayed in 2.3.3 but as a contextual menu which i don't want.

**What i want is (Captured in 4.2.2)**

[image]

The code written above works perfectly and give me the desired result and also i can set the image alongwith menuitem,but if i run the same code in the 2.3 the same code gives me the menu as contextual menu.

so what i am missing?
what changes i need to do achieve my desired output in 2.3 which i am getting in 3.0 + ?

Hope my question is clear...

any help/links will be appreciated....

Thanks in advance....

EDIT :: (after applying commonsware's answer)

modified `menu.xml` ( I hope i am understand it correctly)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:DetailsPage="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
        DetailsPage:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        DetailsPage:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        android:title="Search Products">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_Home"
        DetailsPage:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Home"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_favourite"
        DetailsPage:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="favourite"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_Balance"
        DetailsPage:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Balance"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
        DetailsPage:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Logout"/>

</menu>
```

Output ::

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had one similar issue, and the way I solved it, was to use custom namespaces eg:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:title="@string/logout"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

However I don't know if this is the solution or a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.I have alreday added the my own namespace in the xml file.so i guess that won't be the issue.

Comment: This is not a workaround, see [the Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems) specially **Using XML attributes from the support library** part.

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Remove the `<item>` whose icon is `"@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light`

Step #2: Move the `<item>` elements that had been in the submenu of the above menu item into the main `<menu>` element

Step #3: For those you want to always appear in the overflow, use `DetailsPage:showAsAction="never"`

And you're done.

The overflow is not a submenu. The overflow is part of the regular action bar, which is why your submenu is interfering with your result.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.I have applied your logic to my current code and it does not give me the required output.I hope i have understood your logic properly.Please correct me if i am wrong.Please check my edit..

Comment: @AndroidLearner: What you have is correct. Your device or emulator has a MENU button, in which case pressing the MENU button will cause the overflow to appear from the bottom of the screen. The `...` is only for devices that do not have an off-screen MENU button, such as most tablets.

Comment: so is there any workaround to achieve the my requirement? In 2.3 if i use the old layout(menu.xml) and on click of that i display the menu like i want ?But that should also work on the 3.0 +. So any solution to achieve that?

Comment: @AndroidLearner: The requirement is invalid. Please follow the design guidelines and follow the conventions that users are used to. Your app's users, on devices with a MENU button, use that MENU button to access the overflow.